# SQL Server + comparing output results

Tags: sql-server

I have a bit of difficulty in trying to compare some results, basically

> (SELECT [DishId] FROM [Package_Set_Dish] WHERE [Package_Set_Id] =
>   COALESCE((SELECT [SetId] FROM [Package_Schedule_Set_Daily] WHERE
>   [AutoId] = @PkSchSetId), (SELECT [SetId] FROM
>   [Package_Schedule_Set_Weekly] WHERE [AutoId] = @PkSchSetId)

will return 3 records (Not in sequence):

```
1
2
10
```

or

```
1
10
2
```

Basically, if incoming sproc variables @Dish_1, @Dish_2, @Dish_3 contains exactly 1,2 and 10, I will return a 1 (True). If it contains, 1,2,2 or 1,10,10 it should return 0.

Apparently, the query below is not going to return the desired results. Can anyone advice. Thanks.

```
SET @TempBit = (SELECT CASE WHEN 
          (@Dish_1 IN (SELECT [DishId] FROM [Package_Set_Dish] WHERE [Package_Set_Id] 
     = COALESCE((SELECT [SetId] FROM [Package_Schedule_Set_Daily] 
         WHERE [AutoId] = @PkSchSetId),
       (SELECT [SetId] FROM [Package_Schedule_Set_Weekly] WHERE [AutoId] = @PkSchSetId))) 
       AND @Dish_2 IN (SELECT [DishId] FROM [Package_Set_Dish] WHERE [Package_Set_Id] 
     = COALESCE((SELECT [SetId] FROM [Package_Schedule_Set_Daily] 
      WHERE [AutoId] = @PkSchSetId)
     , (SELECT [SetId] FROM [Package_Schedule_Set_Weekly] WHERE [AutoId] = @PkSchSetId)))
      AND @Dish_3 IN (SELECT [DishId] FROM [Package_Set_Dish] WHERE [Package_Set_Id] 
          = COALESCE((SELECT [SetId] FROM [Package_Schedule_Set_Daily]
       WHERE [AutoId] = @PkSchSetId)
     , (SELECT [SetId] FROM [Package_Schedule_Set_Weekly] WHERE [AutoId] = @PkSchSetId)))                                    
AND (SELECT [Date] FROM [Customer_Order_SwapSetDish] 
         WHERE [CustOrderId] = @CustOrderId) = @Date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT [DishId]
FROM [Package_Set_Dish]
WHERE [Package_Set_Id] = COALESCE((SELECT [SetId]
                                   FROM [Package_Schedule_Set_Daily]
                                   WHERE [AutoId] = @PkSchSetId
                                  ),
                                  (SELECT [SetId]
                                   FROM [Package_Schedule_Set_Weekly]
                                   WHERE [AutoId] = @PkSchSetId
                                  ))
```

You can do your test with a `having` clause

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM [Package_Set_Dish]
WHERE [Package_Set_Id] = COALESCE((SELECT [SetId]
                                   FROM [Package_Schedule_Set_Daily]
                                   WHERE [AutoId] = @PkSchSetId
                                  ),
                                  (SELECT [SetId]
                                   FROM [Package_Schedule_Set_Weekly]
                                   WHERE [AutoId] = @PkSchSetId
                                  ))
having sum(case when DishId = @DishId1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when DishId = @DishId2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when DishId = @DishId3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

If all three records match, then the query will return 1.  If there is a mismatch, then it will return `NULL`.

Or, you can do it in the `select`:

```
SELECT (case when sum(case when DishId = @DishId1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                  sum(case when DishId = @DishId2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                  sum(case when DishId = @DishId3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 1 else 0
        end) as AreAllThere
FROM [Package_Set_Dish]
WHERE [Package_Set_Id] = COALESCE((SELECT [SetId]
                                   FROM [Package_Schedule_Set_Daily]
                                   WHERE [AutoId] = @PkSchSetId
                                  ),
                                  (SELECT [SetId]
                                   FROM [Package_Schedule_Set_Weekly]
                                   WHERE [AutoId] = @PkSchSetId
                                  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to compare the results of your query with a set of the values of three variables. You can use the `except` and `union` statements to implement the symmetric difference:

```
select case when count(*)=0 then 1 else 0 end
from
(
  (
    (SELECT [DishId] as col FROM [Package_Set_Dish] WHERE [Package_Set_Id] = COALESCE((SELECT [SetId] FROM [Package_Schedule_Set_Daily] WHERE [AutoId] = @PkSchSetId), (SELECT [SetId] FROM [Package_Schedule_Set_Weekly] WHERE [AutoId] = @PkSchSetId)))
    except
    (select @Dish_1 as col union @Dish_2 as col union @Dish_3 as col)
  )
  union
  (
    (select @Dish_1 as col union @Dish_2 as col union @Dish_3 as col)   
    except
    (SELECT [DishId] as col FROM [Package_Set_Dish] WHERE [Package_Set_Id] = COALESCE((SELECT [SetId] FROM [Package_Schedule_Set_Daily] WHERE [AutoId] = @PkSchSetId), (SELECT [SetId] FROM [Package_Schedule_Set_Weekly] WHERE [AutoId] = @PkSchSetId)))
  )
) t;
```